For a non-finitely generated $M$ over an Artinian ring $R$, is $M \simeq P \oplus N$ with $P$ projective and $N$ without non-zero projective summands?
If $R$ is a left Artinian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated left module over $R$, then we have $M \simeq P \oplus N$, where $P$ is a projective module and $N$ has no non-zero projective summand. The following paragraphs provide a detailed explanation.

Since $M$ is a finitely generated left module over the left Artinian ring $R$, it follows that $M$ is also an Artinian module over $R$. Because a left Artinian ring is also a left Noetherian ring, and since $M$ is finitely generated over $R$, $M$ is a Noetherian module over $R$. Therefore, $M$ is a finite-length module over $R$, allowing us to decompose $M$ uniquely as $M \simeq L_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_l \oplus N_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus N_n$, where $L_i$ and $N_i$ are indecomposable modules. We can assume that the $L_i$ are projective and the $N_i$ are not projective. Letting $P = L_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_l$ and $N = N_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus N_n$, we obtain $M \simeq P \oplus N$, where $P$ is a projective module and $N$ has no non-zero projective summand.


If $X \neq 0$ is a direct summand of $N$, then $X$ is a finite-length module because $N$ is a finite-length module. So we have a decomposition $X \simeq X_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus X_k$, where each $X_i$ is an indecomposable module. According to the uniqueness of the decomposition of the finite-length module $N$, for any $X_i$ there exists an $N_j$ such that $X_i \simeq N_j$. Therefore, $X_i$ is not a projective module for $1 \leq i \leq k$, and thus $X \simeq X_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus X_k$ is not a projective module. Therefore, $N$ has no non-zero projective summand.

Now, the question arises:

if $M$ is a non-finitely generated module over a left Artinian ring $R$, can we also get $M \simeq P \oplus N$, where $P$ is a projective module and $N$ has no non-zero projective summand?


Can you add a reference for the f.g. case which shows the proof?

@Martin Brandenburg Thank you! I’ve added a detailed explanation above.

Alternatively in the f.g. case, without the decomposition argument, one can imagine increasing chains of projective summands inductively constructed by extracting projective summands out of one half. The module is both Noetherian (in addition to being Artinian) so it'd have to terminate at some point.

So to put it another way it looks like a Noetherian module over any ring has this property.
